# Python ctypes passing string pointer / buffer

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am trying to get information from a sensor through its DLL with Python.
I never worked with ctypes or C in general before so I lack some knowlege about this, hopefully somebody can help me.
Calling the functions work so far but I cannot get the functions to give back string information.
What works so far:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = windll.LoadLibrary("MEDAQLib.dll")

version = create_string_buffer(15)
libc.GetDLLVersion(version, 15)
print(version.value.decode())
```

This returns the version number of the DLL and works correctly.
Now I try to get some information about the sensor in the same way.

```
# Create sensor instance and open connection
sensor = libc.CreateSensorInstance(42)
libc.OpenSensorRS232(sensor, b'COM4')

# Try to get information from sensor
name = create_string_buffer(32)
libc.ExecSCmdGetString(sensor, b'Get_Info', b'SA_Sensor', name, 32)
print(name.value.decode())
```

The *ExecSCmdGetString* function failes with `OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000020`

**Declaration** for *GetDLLVersion*:
`ERR_CODE GetDLLVersion (char *versionStr, uint32_t maxLen);`
**Parameter:**
uint32_t maxLen
**Description:**
Length of string buffer. If the version info is longer as
maxLen it is truncated. The string is null terminated.

**Declaration** for *ExecSCmdGetString*:
`ERR_CODE ExecSCmdGetString (uint32_t instanceHandle, const char *sensorCommand,
const char *paramName, char *paramValue, uint32_t *maxLen);`
**Parameter:**
uint32_t * maxLen
**Description:**
The buffer must be allocated by the application. The size of
the buffer is specified at maxLen. If the resulting string is larger than
maxLen, it is truncated and ERR_NOMEMORY (-19) is returned. The
real length of the string (maybe truncated) is returned in maxLen too.
If paramValue is nullptr, the length of the containing string is returned
in maxLen.

So obviously I cannot just specify the *maxLen* as an integer anymore.
But how do I have to do it then?

I also tried to just make a pointer:

```
name = c_char_p()
libc.ExecSCmdGetString(sensor, b'Get_Info', b'SA_Sensor', byref(name))
```

But then how do I specify *maxLen*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
paramValue = create_string_buffer(32)
maxLen = c_uint32(32)
errCode = libc.ExecSCmdGetString(sensor, b'Get_Info', b'SA_Sensor', paramValue, byref(maxLen))
```

Your first attempt didn't work because `maxLen` is a `uint32_t *`, but you just passed it a `uint32_t`. Wrapping it in `byref()` fixes this.